# Why are the Buttons at the top of my carousel not working?

Tags: html, css, sass

Why are the buttons at the top of my carousel not working?

Check out the link to the codepen here:
https://codepen.io/foersterrobert/pen/pobGBJP

I got most of the carousel code from here: https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/

But somehow the #jumplinks in my version aren't working!

I hope you can help.

HTML:

```
   <div class="slider">
   <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
   <a href="#slide-2">2</a>

   <div id="strom" class="strom">

     <div id="#slide-1">
        <h5 class="intro__text">
          Strom
        </h5>
     </div>

    <div id="#slide-2" class="strom__bundesländer">
       <div class="strom__bundesländer__map">
       <h3 class="intro__title">Bundesländer</h3>
    </div>

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.slider {
width: 80%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 40px auto;

& > a {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
    position: relative;
  }

& > a:active {
    top: 1px;
  }

& > a:focus {
    background: #000;
  }
}

.strom {
display: flex;
overflow-x: auto;
scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;


&::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
&::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
  }

& > div {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 50px;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    position: relative;

    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #8a8a85;
    }
    }
```

Would love to hear your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used # on your id. Just remove hash.Corrections are given bellow.

```html
<div id="slide-1">
        
</div>

<div id="slide-2" class="strom__bundesländer">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That truly was a stupid mistake.

Comment: @RobertFörster it's not stupidity. Sometimes it happened. Common mistakes are occurred. If you got the answer then you can mark this as your answer

Answer (score 0):

Hello Robert you made error in the div section where the id value will not have '#' prefix to it. Just remove that.

HTML:

```
 <div id="slide-1">
    <h5 class="intro__text">
      Strom
    </h5>
 </div>

 <div id="slide-2" class="strom__bundesländer">
   <div class="strom__bundesländer__map">
     <h3 class="intro__title">Bundesländer</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```